# SQL Select where IN (array) returns only when first item in array found

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, where-clause

SQL in 'services' column I have an arrays values like e.g.: 2,19,72,5,46,45,38,40,36,27,29

For selecting this row from DB I'm using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `services` IN (2,19)
```

And it is working OK. But, when I do changes in 'IN' closure like below:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `services` IN (19)
```

it always returns 0 rows. The query is searching only for the first value in column.
Why this is happening and how can I change my query to work it correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the structure myTable? Data types, etc.

Comment: Write query as SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE services IN (2,19)

Comment: Services column have values like 2,19,72,5,46,45,38,40,36,27,29 ?

Comment: And make sure that your sevices column has 19 value

Comment: what is the DataType of your column `services`?? is it int or varchar ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query like :
If you search only single value...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE concat(',',`services`,',') like '%19%'
```

But if you want to search 19,2 or 2,40 or 40,19 it will not work. for that case you need to write query dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
$recordsArr = [2,19,72,5,46,45,38,40,36,27,29]; // Your array
$records = implode(',', $recordsArr);  // Your string
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE services IN( $records )"; // Your query
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is stored as TEXT, so you need to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE `services` LIKE '%,2,%' OR `services` LIKE '2,%' OR `services` LIKE '%,2' OR services` LIKE '%,19,%' OR `services` LIKE '19,%' OR `services` LIKE '%,19'
```

This is very slow and will get complicated very fast. You should find another way to store your data.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$array','services')